# Addition of two random number, with a different setTimeout ( Code almost working )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple code to add two random numbers.

Number 1 is minimum 1000 and maximum 2000.
It changes every 10 seconds.

Number 2 is minimum 1 and maximum 5.
It changes much faster ( delay is random )

The point is to addition number 1 + number 2, and "refresh" the total everytime number 2 changed.

Thanks in advance :)

```
function bignumber() {
var bignumber = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  $('#bignumber').text(bignumber);  
  return bignumber;
  setTimeout(Big, 2300);
}

bignumber()

function addition() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 5 + 1) + 5);
  var smallnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1) + 1);

var result = ??How to place Number1 here?? + smallnumber;

  $('#smallnumber').text(result);  
   setTimeout(myFunction, rand * 300);
}

addition()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `var bignumber` outside function scope and update its value on function one also read value in function two

```
 var bignumber =0 ; 
 function bignumber() {
  bignumber = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
   ......

   function addition() {
    ....
     var result = bignumber + smallnumber;

     ...`
```